# Hartshorne III Example 9.8.4, how to understand a parameterization of a curve by scheme-language

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, flatness

For each $a\in \mathbb A^1 -\{0\}$ the scheme $X_a$ is given by
$$
x=t^2-1,~ ~~y = t^3-t,~~~ z=at
$$
and then we have a family over $\mathbb A^1 -\{0\}$. Our goal is to obtain the total family $\bar X$ over $\mathbb A^1$. So, we want to find the ideal $I\subset k[x,y,z,a]$ of the total family $\bar X$. A mystery to me is the way Hartshorne obtain the ideal (without any explanation)
$$
I = (a^2(x+1）- z^2, ax(x+1) -yz, xz-ay, y^2,x^2(x+1))
$$

My naive attempt is simply use the third equation to eliminate $t$ and get an ideal $(a^2(x+1)-z^2, a^3y+a^2z-z^3)$. I know this is not correct but I don't know why.

Furthermore, from a scheme-theoretic point of view, the total family $\bar X$ is obtained by taking scheme-theoretic closure (see Proposition 9.8), and this can be determined by an ideal sheaf shown in Stack Project [28.6.1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01R5). I was wondering if we can explain the method here using the language of scheme.

In particular, what does a parametrization (of a curve e.g. $X_a$ above) tell us in the view of scheme? (Learning scheme-language make it hard for me to understand even a curve, and I am always trying to write down things as Spec of some rings. This is not good!)

Comment: What you wrote is incomprehensible for people who do not have the book at hand. That's bad practice.

Comment: I see and I will edit my post @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot write down everything, because that would be too long. Actually this example follows the preceding discussion in Example 9.8.3, which is related to Projection from a Point. @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Hartshorne has obtained this ideal is due to the line "and make sure $a$ is not a zero divisor". If you try to find the equations defining this ideal (and it is an ideal, you don't need a sheaf of ideals, because he is considering a single affine chart in both projective spaces, which contains the double point) and simply quotient by those equations, you will find that $a$ becomes a zero divisor in the quotient. Thus you also quotient by the equations that make this happen. I know this is a very old question, but hopefully this helps if anyone gets confused like I did reading through this example and turns to google.